# How to automate locale settings

Tags: powershell, windows-phone-8

I have to automate the locale settings for Windows Phone (Lumia 1020 with windows 8), which is connected to my PC through a USB cable. Tried these ways like open the device to do locale settings, used powershell commands like:

```
open-device "DeviceID "
```

But it's not tracing. Preferably know in built function like:

```
Get-winsystemlocale
Set-winsystemlocale "en-us"
```

Suggest the best approach to accomplish this without using any tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use undocumented Microsoft.Smartdevice.* API to do developer unlock the device.

You can use UI Automation API (or higher-level, but slower, buggy, and worse documented Coded UI API) to implement DLL for the device that implements a coded UI test that will change the locale however you want by detecting state of the UI and faking user’s input.

Then you can use command-line vstest.console.exe to launch that test on the device.

This is technically hard, the solution is fragile (i.e. may break with the windows phone upgrade); however I don’t know better solutions for you.